# Running a single test configuration with xcodebuild

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

I am trying to execute some tests from CLI with `xcodebuild`, it works well but I would like to make the process faster. I have a Test Plan which includes 5 configurations (one for every language supported by the app) and I would like to be able to tell which language to use (not all of them).

Basically I would like to do this

[image]

But from command line.

I tried different solutions like

```
xcodebuild test ... -testPlan XXX
                    -testLanguage en
                    -testRegion GB
```

or

```
xcodebuild test ... -only-testing:XXXTests/XXXClass/XXXMethod/en_GB
```

But unfortunately none of them worked. I also did not find any documentation about this so unfortunately I am starting to think it's not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how to specify only certain configuration

```
-only-test-configuration {configuration_name}
```

This is how to exclude a configuration

```
-skip-test-configuration {configuration_name}
```

Comment: glad to hear! FYI, i got it while looking through `man xcodebuild`. this is not a rtfm, first time i was doing this myself :D